# I've created an iOS app powered by a Laravel API - how do I save and return text that contains emojis?

Tags: php, api, laravel, emoji, lumen

I have  created an iOS app powered by a Laravel API using lumen framework how do I save and return text that contains emojis?

i set charset to utf8mb4 for database but it was not working.

when i was try to save these emojis it save as ??????

Answer (score 1):

You should maybe store them as a caption so for example **:happy** for a happy emoticon etc. And in your app you just filter them out and replace them with the emoticon.